# Поиск без учета регистра

Tags: oracle

Одним из методов сделать поиск строк в таблице без учета регистра есть использование индексов:

```
create index nlsci1_gen_person on table_b
   (NLSSORT
      (value, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI')
   );

create index my_index on table_b ( lower(value) );
```

Есть таблица и в ней есть запись VALUE со значением 'A' (большая буква) и 'a' (маленькая буква). Я хочу получить их из выборки, используя мощь этих индексов.
Индексы я так создал, но:

```
SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE value = 'a';
```

запрос не возвращает строк 'A'.

Я знаю, что можно использовать функции UPPER, LOWER

```
SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE LOWER(value) = 'a';
```

Но я прочитал, что для больших таблиц этот способ очень медленный, поэтому решил использовать мощь индексов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что Вы забыли изменить настройки `NLS_COMP` и `NLS_SORT`для того, чтобы поиск строк работал правильно:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;

SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE value = 'a';
```

**[Sql Fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e70f71/3)** отрабатывает нормально.

---

> Но я прочитал, что для больших таблиц этот способ очень медленный,
>   поэтому решил использовать мощь индексов.

Мне кажется, что это справедливо если нет соответствующего индекса и выполняется `FULL TABLE SCAN` и применение функции `LOWER` к каждой строке. В своем примере Вы же создаете индекс `lower(value)` которые нормально будет использоваться в Вашем же запросе

```
SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE LOWER(value) = 'a';
```

В таком случае и `FULL TABLE SCAN` не происходит и конвертация строки функцией `LOWER` тоже не происходит, а выполняется сканирование индекса.

Comment: Тоесть если создали индекс on table_b ( lower(value) ) то в запросе оставлять  WHERE LOWER(value) = 'a'  и индекс будет ускорять поиск? Я думал можно опустить  LOWER в запросе после создания индекса .

Comment: Да, оставлять надо. Тогда `Oracle` понимает, что может использовать соответствующий индекс.

Comment: Благодарен Вам за помощь . А что на счет использования первого индекса 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI' ?

Comment: Если Вы правильно укажите параметры `NLS_COMP` и `NLS_SORT`, то `Oracle` будет использовать такой индекс для поиска строк тоже. Если в [примере](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79da36/1) посмотреть план запроса `View Execution Plan`, то видно, что индекс используется.